# Send ajax without submitting form(onchange)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two ajax in my page the one works fine, but the other one is not working. I tried to send ajax post method without submitting a form, just using onchange method but not triggering, I debug my codes it only trigger if a reload the page.

i also tried to modify code on triggering change method:

```
$('#sheets').onchange(function () {}
```

first ajax that works fine:

```
<script>
$('#modal-set__btn').click(function (e) {

    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
        var fileUpload = $('#file-input').get(0);
        console.log(fileUpload);
        var files = fileUpload.files;

        var fileData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            alert(files[i].name + " and " + files[i]);
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }

        alert(files.length);

    }

    var url = '/' + 'Page/Inventory/Item/Index/fileUpload';
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fileData,
        success: function (response) {
            var result = $(response).find("#tablecollection").html();
            console.log('Response:', result);
            $('#tablecollection').html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error_m) {
            alert('AJAX request failed +' + error_m);
        }
    });
    tempArr.length = 0;
});
```

my second ajax that doesn't work:

```
$('#sheets').on('change', function () {
    var _sheet = $('#sheet_val').val();
    var array = {
        sheet: _sheet
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + 'Page/Inventory/Item/Index/sheetData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: array,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#tableData').html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error_m) {
            alert('AJAX request failed +' + error_m);
        }
    });
});
```

this is my cshtml:

```
<div id="tablecollection">
@using System.Data

@if (ViewBag.DataSet != null && ViewBag.DataTable != null)
{

    <label for="sheets">Choose a Sheet:</label>
    <select name="sheets" id="sheets">

        @{
            DataTableCollection dataTables = ViewBag.DataTable;

            foreach (DataTable item in dataTables)
            {
                <option id="sheet_val" value="@item.TableName">@item.TableName</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
}
```

Comment: share the html also, which input type is #sheets?

Comment: @YuvarajM okay, just posted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you create the same Id <option id="sheet_val" that is bad html, change your id to class

```
<option class="sheet_val" value="@item.TableName">@item.TableName</option>
```

then

```
var _sheet = $('.sheet_val:selected').val();
```

now try the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // First AJAX call that works fine:
    $('#modal-set__btn').click(function(e) {
        // ... (This section remains unchanged based on the info you provided)
    });

        // Use event delegation to handle changes, especially useful if content is dynamically loaded
        $(document).on('change', '#sheets', function() {
            var _sheet = $('.sheet_val:selected').val();
            var array = {
                sheet: _sheet
            };
    
            $.ajax({
                url: '/' + 'Page/Inventory/Item/Index/sheetData',
                type: 'POST',
                data: array,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    // Fixed the variable name here from result to response
                    $('#tableData').html(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error_m) {
                    alert('AJAX request failed +' + error_m);
                }
            });
        });
    
    });
```

Comment: it is the same, the change method is not triggering

Comment: add alert("test") after $(document).on('change', '#sheets', function() { see it it works

Comment: oh, i remember when testing it in the console,  this code works when I type it in console:
"$('#sheets').on('change', function(){
    alert("changing")
}) "

Comment: so the on change is triggering, now check if you get the var _sheet = $('.sheet_val:selected').val(); if you do check the api

Comment: OH, it actually works, after reviewing my code I made some typos so it is not working, but after checking it works now. thanks

Comment: " $(document).on('change', '#sheets', function()" 
may i know in this code what is the second parameter of on method?

Comment: before i check the answer you wrote, just want to know what exactly wrong in my code for not triggering the change?

Comment: my guess is the  document.ready function, it makes sure the DOM is fully loaded before executing your scripts. or the ids you've created